# Tensorflow model zoo?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

One of the main advantages of caffe for me was the possibility of doing transfer learning on freely distributed pretrained models.

Is there a place to get trained models from papers/competitions in tensorflow format?

If not, is there a possibility to convert existing caffe(or any other) models into tensorflow models?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can likely use the [caffe to tensorflow model converter](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow) to convert [model zoo](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Model-Zoo) models.  If you try it and report back, it would be great to know.  There's a potential issue with [converting maxpooling and padding](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow/issues/3), but it seems to work for many models.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, official TF github page has a [list with the group of models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models). Also you can use [keras.applications](https://keras.io/applications/) which has pretrained models.

Comment: Repository `fchollet/deep-learning-models` has been deprecated. Module `keras.applications` should be used instead. Please update the link.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do transfer learning with Tensorflow some of which combine TF Slim and custom codes, but there is a very nice collection of pretrained Tensorflow models [Tensornets](https://github.com/taehoonlee/tensornets) which contain almost all popular models and their pretrained weights

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do Transfer learning in TFlow.
1st solution is to write your save/load on checkpoints. However, there are incompatibilities with TF 1.0 and TF 2.0

Other one is to used some pre-framework on top of TF, some of them are :
   TFLayers : TF specific:  [TF Slim](https://github.com/google-research/tf-slim)
   MLModels : Cross platform model zoo: [MLmodels](https://github.com/arita37/mlmodels/)